# AngularJS - multiselect options when model and options are different

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple select box for user to select his roles.

```
<select ng-options="role.name for role in roles"
        ng-model="user.roles"
        multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

**"roles"** - is the list of roles that user can select

`[{"id":1,"name":"Moderator"},{"id":2,"name":"Admin"}]`

**"user.roles"** - list of roles that user actually have

`{"id":5,"email":"la@la.la","roles":[{"id":2,"name":"Admin"}]}`

Both "roles" and "user" are loading dynamically via ajax.
The problem is that when I load user that already have roles - they are not automatically selected in the select box. How do I select them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your version of angular ?

In angular 1.0.X, angular check if items are strictly equals (so roles must be the same instance in ng-model and selected item in array).

If you use a more recent version of angular (1.2.x), you can use 'track by' in your ng-option:

```
<select
    ng-options="role.name for role in roles track by role.name"
    ng-model="user.roles"
    multiple>
</select>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJLwp/2

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I have found the solution. If anybody can suggest better solution, please post it

**function to check if role exists in the given array of roles**

```
$scope.isRoleContains = function(roles, roleToFind) {
    var is = false;
    angular.forEach(roles, function(role) {
        if (role.name == roleToFind.name)
            is = true;
    });
    return is;
}
```

**updated select box**

```
<select ng-model="user.roles" multiple="multiple">
    <option ng-repeat="role in roles" ng-selected="isRoleContains(user.roles, role)">
        {{ role.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only issue is that roles should not contain anything but the key.

```
"roles":[{"id":2}]
```

Here is how you use multi-select: http://jsfiddle.net/vYaNx/3/

You need to have what is selected in your data.  User.roles should be the selected data.

HTML:

```
<select multiple ng:model="selectedColors" ng:options="k as v for (k, v) in colors"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.colors = {
    b: 'black',
    w: 'white',
    r: 'red',
    c: 'cyan',
    y: 'yellow'
  };
  $scope.selectedColors = ['r', 'c'];
```

Comment: sorry, this looks like standard answer, I didnt find answer on my question

Answer (score 0):

H i, Throwing this in to the mix :

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rq2ky/1/

key being the setup of the ng-options ( declaring what the key values are )

```
   <select 
        multiple="multiple" 
        ng-options="obj.name as obj.name for obj in roles" 
        ng-model="user.roles">
</select>
```